# How to get values from child object in action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts, el

I have a `dynaform` `ReservationForm` which is against an object reservation in reservation object there are members and in each member there are billing information objects.
in each billing object i have an service object.
I am showing values from service object while redring billing object    `<html:checkboxname="billingDetailObject"property="memberService.completedFlag">/html:checkbox>`
problem is it is showing checkbox name as `"memberService.completedFlag"` when i view source.
when i try to get this from action form

```
actionForm.get("memberService.completedFlag")
```

it returns me no value even though it has values on UI.

Comment: your description is not clear. please ident it properly and upload the code that you have tried so far

Comment: <form-property name="memberService.completedFlag"
    type="java.lang.Boolean[]" />
this is struts config i have mentioned above in action class how i am getting it from actionForm. I have main Object billingDetailObject in this object I have memberService object which has variable completedFlag

Comment: sorry I if I am not clear enough, It is little difficult for me to explain things in general :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a wrong type in the `form-property` tag. Try

```
<form-property name="memberService.completedFlag" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
```

Comment: I don't think it is wrong because it is working on other places and problem is not with strut-config. problem is with this memberService.completedFlag on jsp when i am taking value from memberService object inside another object. same thing works when i take value from memberService containing object.

Comment: Use JSP EL to access memberService object in JSP or remove it from the form by replacing it with a plain form property.